# TSQL add all data to first row then half the data after

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Hey all I have a table that when I run the query I get something like this:

```
ID |The GUID                 |Quantity |Maint Part Number |Ship Group    |Date Received
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |54219-8974-8702-852-5425 |50       |54VRT             |ShipG105      |06/08/2018
3  |68v3f-5kjd-46ee-586-5988 |10       |M6eR5w            |ShipG001      |10/19/2010
4  |ErR20-bvmd-0001-bGT-0O0O |100      |MRE101            |ShipG99       |01/01/2011
```

Now what I am looking to want to do is this:

```
ID |The GUID                 |Quantity |Maint Part Number |Ship Group    |Date Received
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |54219-8974-8702-852-5425 |50       |54VRT             |ShipG105      |06/08/2018
3  |                         |         |M6eR5w            |ShipG001      |10/19/2010
4  |                         |         |MRE101            |ShipG99       |01/01/2011
```

ALL the data is present on this first record row while the following rows only have the adition data of **inv_...**.

I'm getting all  this data from **multipole INNER JOIN** tables and also **LEFT JOIN** tables.

A Query example:

```
SELECT
   BL.ID                AS 'ID',
   BL.guid              AS 'The GUID',
   BL.qty               AS 'Quantity',
   I.inv_maintPartNum   AS 'Maint Part Number',
   I.inv_ShipGrp        AS 'Ship Group',
   I.inv_DateRec        AS 'Date Received' 
FROM 
   BizLine              AS BL 
INNER JOIN inventory    AS I 
   ON BL.ID = I.ID
..........
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

If I have more records that are of a different ID that looks like this:

```
ID |The GUID                 |Quantity |Maint Part Number |Ship Group    |Date Received
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |54219-8974-8702-852-5425 |50       |54VRT             |ShipG105      |06/08/2018
2  |68v3f-5kjd-46ee-586-5988 |10       |M6eR5w            |ShipG001      |10/19/2010
2  |ErR20-bvmd-0001-bGT-0O0O |100      |MRE101            |ShipG99       |01/01/2011
3  |68rGw-3567-0001-123-fG34 |5        |GRD2859           |ShipG1        |11/11/2012
3  |5879R-376T-FDSW-RT7-23FG |1005     |Sv22              |ShipG87       |04/19/2017
```

And now using the query from @SQLChao it looks like this:

```
2  |54219-8974-8702-852-5425 |50       |54VRT             |ShipG105      |06/08/2018
2  |                         |         |M6eR5w            |ShipG001      |10/19/2010
2  |                         |         |MRE101            |ShipG99       |01/01/2011
3  |                         |         |GRD2859           |ShipG1        |11/11/2012
3  |                         |         |Sv22              |ShipG87       |04/19/2017
```

Now what it should look like is this:

```
2  |54219-8974-8702-852-5425 |50       |54VRT             |ShipG105      |06/08/2018
2  |                         |         |M6eR5w            |ShipG001      |10/19/2010
2  |                         |         |MRE101            |ShipG99       |01/01/2011
3  |68rGw-3567-0001-123-fG34 |5        |GRD2859           |ShipG1        |11/11/2012
3  |                         |         |Sv22              |ShipG87       |04/19/2017
```

Notice how **ID 3** starts with all the data just like the first **ID 2** does and then only shows the other data thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and if it is = 1 then return the data. Else leave it blank. I'm not really sure how you are ordering your data so I used `BL.ID`. You can change it to something else if needed.

```
SELECT
   BL.ID                AS 'ID',
   CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BL.ID ORDER BY BL.ID ASC) = 1 THEN BL.guid ELSE '' END AS 'The GUID',
   CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By BL.ID ORDER BY BL.ID ASC) = 1 THEN BL.qty ELSE '' END AS 'Quantity',
   I.inv_maintPartNum   AS 'Maint Part Number',
   I.inv_ShipGrp        AS 'Ship Group',
   I.inv_DateRec        AS 'Date Received' 
FROM 
   BizLine              AS BL 
INNER JOIN inventory    AS I 
   ON BL.ID = I.ID
..........
```

Comment: Nice code @SQLChao and it does work but I forgot to add that I needed it to do the same thing if its a new ID. Please see my OP for the update example of this.

Comment: @StealthRT answer updated. Solution is the same. Added partition by. You still need to chose how to order within the set of ids.

Comment: Great job, SQLChao! Works now just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Would it be possible to save the first CASE into a variable so that my query isn't so large with CASE structures (its currently 230 lines for the query)?

Comment: And I noticed that if the column is an **INT** than instead of placing a **blank** into that cell it puts **0**.

Comment: You'd have to convert the INT to a varchar to make it blank. Or instead of using a blank make them NULL.

Comment: Thanks. Any solution for the CASE?

Comment: You could shorten the amount of code like in the other answer by tolu which is the same overall logic as mine but you are still going to have just as many case statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;With myData as
(
SELECT
   BL.ID                AS 'ID',
   BL.guid              AS 'The GUID',
   BL.qty               AS 'Quantity',
   I.inv_maintPartNum   AS 'Maint Part Number',
   I.inv_ShipGrp        AS 'Ship Group',
   I.inv_DateRec        AS 'Date Received',
   ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By BL.ID Order By BL.ID) RowNo

FROM 
   BizLine              AS BL 
INNER JOIN inventory    AS I 
   ON BL.ID = I.ID

)
Select ID, IIF(RowNo = 1, [The GUID], ' ')  [The GUID], IIF(RowNo = 1, [Quantity], ' ') Quantity, [Maint Part Number], [Ship Group], [Date Received]
From myData
```

You may need to modify the window function to identify the record you want full data for.